# What should `git config -e` do or look like when I run the command? I keep getting notice that the page I'm looking for doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, git, vim, heroku

I am just starting out trying to create a rails app using scaffolding. I used the command: `heroku create` and it made an app on heroku that I could see on heroku.com. the tutorial I was using told me to check if it was working by typing `git config -e` and when I did I guess I opened vim (which I don't know how to use) I think I typed something I don't know what it was and then I wanted to change the name from the randomly generated one it had so I changed the heroku remote url then by looking online I found I could close and save vim by typing the escape key then `:` then `wq` then enter. This closed the window and took me back to command line and I ran `git push heroku master` then `heroku run rake db:migrate` then `heroku open` and I get an error saying the page does not existhttps://i.stack.imgur.com/kJsSp.jpg. Here's a link of what I see when I type `git confi-e`https://i.stack.imgur.com/337We.jpg

Also, I don't quite understand what `git config -e` is or what the -e is. Clarifications are much appreciated.

Thank you for your time,
dlugo06

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read more about `git config` and its options [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html). As the name implies, it allows you to configure setting for git. `-e` is the edit option which will open the git config in your chosen editor (vim by default).

Looking at the image that you have provided there are four sections: core, origin, master, heroku:

**core**

This allows you to specify general configuration for git.

**remote "origin"**

This is your origin branch on github - the one that you push and pull from. You can read more about this [here](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/the-configuration-file-remote-section/)

**branch "master"**

This is the default branch that you pull and push to when a branch is not specified (eg `git push`, `git pull`). You can read more about this [here](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/the-configuration-file-branch-section/)

**remote "heroku"**

This specifies another remote location that you can push to, in this case your Heroku repository.

You can edit your git config at any time using the `git config -e` command. Just make sure that the Heroku repository url matches the one Heroku have provided you.

**Editor**

Lastly, if you are not comfortable with vim you can always change the default editor using the following command:

```
git config --global core.editor "pico"
```

In this case I chose pico but you can choose any editor you like.